# Why are there defined constants and declared constants in CPP?

Tags: c++, constants

Why are there two ways to "declare" constants in CPP?
Which is better, or should I write, which of them should I use when?

```
#define MYCON 100
const int MYCON=100
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short rule: For conditional compilation (like different code fragments for DEBUG and RELEASE) use `#define`. For all other cases use `const` construction.

Comment: +1: good rule of thumb - not sure why someone else gave you a down-vote for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `#define` produces a preprocessor symbol: it has no existence at all after preprocessing has occurred and is equivalent to having typed "100" into the file.

Features of preprocessor symbols:

- You can use them in preprocessor directive like `#ifdef`
- It has lexical scope
- You can *not* take their address (and therefore cannot use them as arguments where a `type*` is expected)

Using `const type` declares a c++ variable.

- You can *not* use this thing in preprocessor directives
- It follows the usual c++ scope rules
- You can takes it's address

It is widely considered better to use `const` for "in program" constants and `#define` only for conditional compilation (which represents a change from the (very!) old days when you could not always rely on c compiler to handle `const` intelligently and using `#define` was preferred). If nothing else this gives you better control of the symbol's scope.

Answer (score 0):

In the original version of C, `#define` was the only method available to declare a constant value. This was done at compile time rather than at run time: The compiler hardcoded the value for each instruction. `const` is a feature of C++ (later added to C in limited fashion), and in C++ it is recommended that you use const rather than #define. `const` variables actually exist in memory, and can be initialized at construction during runtime.

`#define` is, however, still frequently used in C++, mainly for communication with the compiler.

Some examples:

Class header wrappers to prevent multiple class declarations:

```
#ifdef VAL_H
#define VAL_H

// Define class header

#endif // VAL_H
```

Conditional Compilation:

```
// Comment this line to disable debug output
#define DEBUG

// Some code
#ifdef DEBUG
// Only gets compiled if DEBUG is defined.
cerr << "Debug output here" << endl;
#endif
```